# Not getting data from a NodeJs API in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I am trying to **Implement an API in Angular with post request**, **API is working fine in Postman**, but when I Implemented this API in angular data is not posting neither giving me any error, I checked my Network too!

I am getting response in browser

```
{"code":204,"success":"Client Id is not selected!"}
```

status code: `200 ok`

**Payload in Postman:**

```
{"clientid": "D0242"}
```

Payload showing in **my browser:**

[image]

**app.setting**

```
  public static DigestEmailIdPrint = "articles/DigestEmailIdPrint";
```

**service.ts**

```
  DigestEmailIdPrint(clientid) {
return this.http.post<any>(
  this.SERVERURL + this.AppSettings.DigestEmailIdPrint,
  { clientid: clientid }
);
}
```

**app.ts**

```
    ngOnInit(){
      this.DigestEmailIdPrint()   
      }
    DigestEmailIdPrint() {
    var postData = {
      clientid: localStorage.getItem("storageselectedclient"),
    };

    this.article.DigestEmailIdPrint(postData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log("hio");
        if (res.message != "No Record Found") {
          this.DigestEmailIdPrint = res;
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: In `app.ts`, shouldn't you call `this.DigestEmailIdPrint()` inside `ngOnInit`?

Comment: @BrunoFarias oops typo, I have added now!

Comment: Did you remove `this.DigestEmailIdPrint()` from the end of app.ts? How many requests you see going out in the Network tab? Do you see anything at all in the console?

Comment: What is the HTTP Code and response received ?

Comment: @BrunoFarias yes I removed because it lead to recursive call so I removed `this.DigestEmailIdPrint()` from the last

Comment: @Yanis-git I am getting status code: 200 ok

Comment: @Yanis-git response: `{"code":204,"success":"Client Id is not selected!"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your code to because API is waiting for `{ clientid: clientid }` not `{clientid : { clientid: clientid }}`

```
DigestEmailIdPrint(payload) {
  return this.http.post<any>(
  this.SERVERURL + this.AppSettings.DigestEmailIdPrint,
  payload
);
}
```